# One to zero or one relationship in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Let me simplify:

Given two models

`Department` Model

```
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    public Guid? DepartmentManager { get; set; }
```

`Employee` Model

```
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
```

I want to be able to assign one - and only one - Employee as DepartmentManager  for the Department.

Example: Department is Finance. Department Manager is Joe, Blow.

DepartmentManager in Department Model should contain the EmployeeID for Joe Blow from the Employee Model

I think once I get the relationship correct in the models, I will be able to finish the cshtml pages to handle the CRUD correctly.

Thanks,
John

Comment: Your question doesn't really have anything to do with MVC (as a pattern) or the ASP.NET (Core or otherwise) implementation. Are you using Entity Framework 6 or EF Core?

Comment: From my code for the Departments Model: using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc; and, it is not greyed out so I know the page is referencing the library. NuGet package is Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools plus ...Sqlserver v5.0.4 Thanks

Comment: I think you're using an attribute or something else not shown in your question - `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` is not a requirement for working with EF Core. Not a big deal, it just helps to keep your tags limited to what's actually relevant to your question.

Comment: Can you update your question to show a more concrete example of what you're trying to do? EF does require some configuration to create associations between models, either via the fluent API mentioned below or via data attributes - neither of these are included in what you're shown. If you don't have either, that's also relevant, as it shows where an answer needs to start

Comment: @TiesonT. I might be missing something but the tutorial for EF Core from MS does not use either data attributes nor fluent. The first example in my post is from that tutorial.

Comment: It's clear what you want, not where you need help. This is a standard case from EF core documentation.

Comment: @GertArnold One would think. But, I'm not getting it. I have been through the Razor Pages with Entity Framework Core in ASP.NET Core - Tutorial 1 of 8 and worked all the examples for myself and the code work for the tutorial. However, for my current project, EF is not creating the relationship between Department and employee..

Comment: Not trying to annoy you, but your model perfectly accommodates what you want, `public Guid? DepartmentManager` is the minimum you need. It really isn't clear what keeps you from assigning "one - and only one - Employee as DepartmentManager". If `DepartmentManager` has a value, the department has a manager. Maybe you want to combine it with navigation properties, or you struggle how to set up the UI, or the controller, I don't know.

Comment: @John I suppose it is possible to rely on convention and assume EF will match up your keys, if you follow the naming conventions they suggest. That generally only works for simple cases, for what I've seen. That, I prefer to be explicit about the relationships between my models, so I tend to go this route: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#manual-configuration

Comment: @TiesonT. That is my problem I think. I don't want to rely on the convention because eventually that will break. Currently, my department table only has one relationship to the employee table; department manager. For that case the convention works. However, when I want to add assistant manager, the convention fails because I would already have used EmployeeID for the department manager. So, the fluent API seems to be the answer. Maybe I'm missing something though: I assume the relationship would be defined on the Department table: modelBuilder.Entity<Department>().HosOne(d => d.Employee). Yes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming these are your model classes:

```cs
public class Department
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    public Guid? DepartmentManager { get; set; } 
}
```

and

```cs
public class Employee
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
}
```

You have a few options for explicitly configuring the relationships between your entities (your data models).

#### 1. Data Attributes

If you aren't comfortable with the fluent API, you can decorate your models with data attributes, which EF will discover and use when building the model in memory. So, for your case, something like this works:

```cs
[Table(nameof(Department))]
public class Department
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(DepartmentManager))]
    public Guid? DepartmentManagerID { get; set; } 

    public virtual Employee DepartmentManager { get; set; }
}
```

and

```cs
[Table(nameof(Employee))]
public class Employee
{
    public Employee()
    {
        Departments = new HashSet<Department>();
    }

    [Key]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Department> Departments { get; set; }
}
```

The `TableAttribute` is optional - I use it to explicitly state that the table uses the singular naming convention (so the table is called "Department", not "Departments"). `KeyAttribute` should also be optional, since one of EF's conventions is to assume an "ID" field is a primary key, but, again, `[Key]` makes it explicit (sensing a theme here?).

I also would recommend using `DepartmentManagerID` as the foreign key property, rather than `DepartmentManager`, to be consistent. That also lets you add a navigation property, `DepartmentManager`, which can be used to include the Employee record when querying for Departments.

`Employee` can (should?) also have a navigation property, `Departments`, which represents the "many" side of the "one-to-many" relationship between Employee and Department - a Department can only have one Employee (manager), but an Employee can manage many Departments. Making this a `virtual` property allows EF to lazy-load the property, so you can query for Employee records without always getting the associated Departments.

#### 2. Fluent API

The fluent API can be used in addition to the data attributes, or in place off (your choice). I'd still add the relevant navigation properties, so you models would look like this:

```cs
public class Department
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }

    public Guid? DepartmentManagerID { get; set; } 

    public virtual Employee DepartmentManager { get; set; }
}
```

and

```cs
public class Employee
{
    public Employee()
    {
        Departments = new HashSet<Department>();
    }

    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Department> Departments { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in your DbContext class (to keep this simple(ish)), you'd configure your models and their relationships:

```cs
public partial class JohnsDbContext : DbContext
{
    public JohnsDbContext(DbContextOptions<JohnsDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        // To set the table name, uncomment:
        //modelBuilder.Entity<Department>()
        //    .ToTable(nameof(Department));

        modelBuilder.Entity<Department>()
            .HasKey(m => m.ID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Department>()
            .HasOne(m => m.DepartmentManager)           // Department.DepartmentManager
            .WithMany(m => m.Departments)               // Employee.Departments
            .HasForeignKey(m => m.DepartmentManagerID); // Department.DepartmentManagerID


        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
            .HasKey(m => m.ID);
    }
}
```

And that's pretty much the minimum to set up relationships using the fluent API. There are more settings available, which Intellisense will help you discover, should you need them.

Comment: Tieson, Thank you so much for this. It helps me a lot. Except, I think (for this scenario) it would be a one-to-one relationship because there will only be one department manager for each department. For employees who are members  - not the manager - of each department that will be a field in Employee table: DepartmentID. How does that change what you gave me? Again, you have helped tremendously with this and I owe you a six pack of your favorite beverage - unless it's Dom Perignon! :)

Comment: I GOT IT!!!!! Your comment about an employee can manage multiple departments filled the hole in my brain. Once I realized that was the MANY side, it all clicked. You are my salvation!

Comment: You _can_ setup a 1:1 relationship in Entity Framework, but it requires some work. I think I get what you're trying to do, though, which doesn't really require a 1:1 relationship (unless your business rules state that an Employee can manage one and only one Department). I can amend this answer if you want to see the code to add "DepartmentId" to Employee, but I think you've already figured it out.